# How to check if a number is Roman in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, validation

I found this but i don't undertand it:

```sh
if [[ "${ARG//[IVXLCDM]/}" != "" ]]
then
        echo "Wrong input"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly crude test. It uses pattern expansion to assert whether a string is composed only of characters acceptable in Roman numerals w/o checking the semantics.

The `// ... /` would replace any occurrence of any of the characters `IVXLCDM` in the variable. Only if all of them are OK the result would be an empty string.

Why **crude**? Because it would happily accept `MCCM` which is NOT a valid Roman numeral.

Edit:
As @LéaGris pointed out it will also accept an empty string as "Roman" and the test with inequality `!=` is inefficient.

Comment: it also accept an empty string which cannot be considered a Roman number, and inefficiently compare with `!= ""` instead of using `-n`.

Comment: Fair comments, @LéaGris ... mind if I incorporate that in my answer?

Comment: go for it, this is why I did not put an answer, yours is plenty good and even better if you mention the extra details.

Comment: The extended pattern `[[ $ARG != +([IVXLCDM]) ]]` would at least take care of the emptiness problem, but not the MCCM problem